# can any one help me to understand this recursive prolog example?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

***here is the plus code that i don't understand***

```
plus(0,X,X):-natural_number(X).
plus(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- plus(X,Y,Z).
```

***while given :***

```
natural_number(0).
natural_number(s(X)) :- natural_number(X).
```

I don't understand this recursion. If I have `plus(s(0),s(s(s(0))),Z)` how can i get the answer of `1+3=4`?

I need some explanation for the first code. I try that `plus(0,X,X)` will stop the recursion but I think that I do it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's start with `natural_number(P)`. Read this as "P is a natural number". We're given `natural_number(0).`, which tells us that `0` is always a natural number (i.e. there are no conditions that must be met for it to be a fact). `natural_number(s(X)) :- natural_number(X).` tells us that `s(X)` is a natural number if `X` is a natural number. This is the normal inductive definition of natural numbers, but written "backwards" as we read Prolog "Q := P" as "Q is true if P is true".

Now we can look at `plus(P, Q, R)`. Read this as "`plus` is true if P plus Q equals R". We then look at the cases we're given:

1. `plus(0,X,X) :- natural_number(X).`. Read as Adding 0 to X results in X if X is a natural number. This is our inductive base case, and is the natural definition of addition.
2. `plus(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- plus(X,Y,Z).` Read as "Adding the successor of X to Y results in the successor Z if adding X to Y is Z'. If we change the notation, we can read it algebraically as "X + 1 + Y = Z + 1 if X + Y = Z", which is very natural again.

So, to answer you direct question "If I have `plus(s(0),s(s(s(0))),z)`, how can i get the answer of 1+3=4?", let's consider how we can unify something with z each step of the induction

1. Apply the second definition of `plus`, as it's the only one that unifies with the query. `plus(s(0),s(s(s(0))), s(z'))` is true if `plus(0, s(s(s(0))), z')` is true for some `z`
2. Now apply the first definition of plus, as it's the only unifying definition: `plus(0, s(s(s(0))), z')` if `z'` is `s(s(s(0)))` and `s(s(s(0)))` is a natural number.
3. Unwind the definition of `natural_number` a few times on `s(s(s(0)))` to see that is true.
4. So the overall statement is true, if `s(s(s(0)))` is unified with `z'` and `s(z')` is unified with `z`.

So the interpreter returns true, with `z' = s(s(s(0)))` and `z = s(z')`, i.e. `z = s(s(s(s(0))))`. So, `z` is 4.

Comment: did you mean that z' comes from the first step? this one? Apply the second definition of plus, as it's the only one that unifies with the query. plus(s(0),s(s(s(0))),z) is true if plus(0, s(s(s(0))), z) is true for some z ((the some z is z' and in the plus(0, s(s(s(0))), z') is z' not z)))??

Answer (score 1):

You won't get numerical terms like `1+3=4`, all you get is the term `s/1` which can embed itself to any depth and thus can represent any natural number. You can combine such terms (using `plus/3`) and thereby achieve summing.

Note that your definition of `plus/3` has nothing to do with SWI-Prolog's built-in `plus/3` (which works with integers and not with the `s/1` terms):

```
?- help(plus).
plus(?Int1, ?Int2, ?Int3)
    True if Int3 = Int1 + Int2.
    At least two of the three arguments must be instantiated to integers.
```

Comment: @aseed I understand that your example used s/1. I mentioned the SWI plus/3 because I thought that you were confused by these two different approaches to plus/3. Why else did you tag your question by 'swi-prolog'?

Comment: by mistake i think that it is the same thing

Answer (score 1):

That code is a straightforward implementation of [addition in Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_arithmetic#Addition).

In Peano arithmetic, natural numbers are represented using the constant `0` and the unary function `s`. So `s(0)` is a representation of 1, `s(s(s(0)))` is representation of 3. And `plus(s(0),s(s(s(0))),Z)` will give you `Z = s(s(s(s(0))))`, which is a representation of 4.

Comment: i think that you don't understand my question, thanks any way

Comment: Could you tell me in what way did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: that i know that this is peano arithmetic, and i ask how the recursive in this example works